# Let X ∼ Expo(λ). You can assume you know that λX ∼ Expo(1), and that the nth moment of an Expo(1) random variable is n!. Find the skewness of X.

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

This is a question for class. My prof has given me some guidance but I can't wrap my mind around it.

My prof said I should start by considering the equation for skewness very generically, and use the moment generating function. He also gave me a demonstration of swapping the interior of the skewness equation:

Skew($X$) = $\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{X - E(X)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}}\right)^3$

Then I know some properties of an exponential distribution:
$E(X) = \frac{1}{\lambda}, Var(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}, SD(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$

So with that I can say that:
$\frac{X-E(X)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} = \frac{x-\frac{1}{\lambda}}{\frac{1}{\lambda}} = \lambda x -1$

therefore,
$Skew(X) = E(\lambda x -1)^3$

let $\lambda X = Y$, and expand $(Y-1)^3$ to $Y^3-3Y^2+3Y-1$

Then, because I am given that the nth moment of an Expo(1) random variable is n!, I can say: $Y^3 = 3!, Y^2 = 2!, Y = 1!$

And therefore:

$Y^3-3Y^2+3Y-1 = 3! -3(2!) + 3(1!) - 1 = 6 - 6 + 3 - 1 =2$

Comment: On LHS I see $X$ and on RHS I see $x$. Why? Actually if $X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then $\lambda X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1$. So $\mathsf{Skew}(X)=\mathbb E(Y-1)^3$ where $Y$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

Comment: With respect to the Xs, I was trying to parse what my professor wrote exactly because I am very confused, but it was handwritten quickly. I probably just misread and am using the wrong X.

Comment: I suspect your professor wanted to make clear that $\mathsf{Skew}(X)$ can be found by calculation of $\mathbb E(Y-1)^3$ where $Y$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1$. Eventually you could use the MGF of $Y$ or of $(Y-1)$ for that.

Comment: Ok, so Skew(X) = $E(Y-1)^3$ (where $Y=\lambda X$), but I'm not sure how to use the MGF to find that value.

Comment: Have a look [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) . Also you can do without, work out $(Y-1)^3$ and find the moments of $Y,Y^2,Y^3$.

Comment: Based on your suggestion that I can do without the MGF and find the moments $Y, Y^2, Y^3$, I have edited the post. Does the work shown now make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Also it is confirmed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) that the skew must equalize $2$.